# Check if exists in Array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, if-statement

I'm creating a program in Flash using Actionscript 3.
I was woundering if I could write an «if-statement» that checks if the text the user inputs is already in an array.

Like, if you have an array:

```
var alphabet:Array = new Array("a","b","c","d","e")
```

I want to make a statement like

If ('a' exist in alphabet)

Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: It would be nice if you close the question somehow, because it's important to not leave unanswered questions - people keep looking at them as they think they can help.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `indexOf` to find if the element is in the Array:

```
if (alphabet.indexOf('c') != -1) {
    // the element is there
}
```

`indexOf` actually returns the position at which the element is found, and -1 if the element is missing. So this is a simple check.

Answer (score 0):

If your array is filled with random entries, you should parse the array one by one.

You can create a function which you supply the parameters of the array and the string you search for like this one.

```
static public function checkIfExists(txt:String, array:Array):Boolean 
{
    for (var i:int = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
    {
        if (array[i] == txt) 
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then you can call it by

```
checkIfExists('a', alphabet);
```